# How to setup Adhoc between Kubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, network-manager, adhoc

So I'm in a temporary situation. If I get the answer later, I still would like to know the answer. I have 2 laptops, laptop 1 is and old pentium m running Ubuntu 12.04 (The last supported OS for it.) Laptop 2 is a much newer laptop running Kubuntu 12.10. I have a single ethernet connection where I am but no wireless router coming for another few weeks. I had no problem setting up an Adhoc network from Laptop 1 to laptop 2 by simply clicking on the network icon > Create New Wireless Network... > entering an SSID and Key, Select Create and then pulling up Laptop 2, selecting the network icon, seeing the available connection and connecting. Really simple, worked great. However, When I tried to reverse the setup and make Laptop 2 the host connected to the internet, I discovered there is no "Create New Wireless Network..." option. When I goto Manage connections and setup a new connection as Adhoc. If I leave the IPV4 settings alone I can get Laptop 1 to connect to it, but no internet. If I change the IPV4 settings to "Share" on Laptop 2, laptop 1 just tries to connect for 5 minutes and never successfully does. The heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if this applies but I have Ubuntu 12.10 and to set up a "Adhoc" for my older laptop I simply open System Settings, Go To Network, Click Wireless, and hit Use as Hotspot.
Look here for a more in depth tutorial:
[How to Turn Your Ubuntu Laptop into a Wireless Access Point](http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/).

Comment: Unfortunately, Kubuntu does not have the same network manager as Ubuntu.

Comment: I just discovered what I had been doing wrong. I had set up the security in Kubuntu as WEP 128-Passphrase and then on the other machine was trying to connect with a WEP 40/128-hex key. The mistake was on me. Sorry, and thank you rockon999 for responding.